# Dynamic Image grid arrangement in Android

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, staggeredgridlayout

I'm working on an app that receives random amount of images and should show them to the user in a grid. Grid cells depends on the amount of Images.  Max is 5. Something like what Facebook does:
[image: Facebook Timeline]

Notice how the grid changes based on the image dimensions but still in a fixed image space. I tried using staggered grid but it just creates a long list and I'm not exactly good at staggered grid layout myself. Another option is to use grid view but I couldn't programmatically change the dimensions of the grid cells. Any help would be appreciated

I should Mention I'm using Xamarin.Android

Comment: try this: https://github.com/smanikandan14/StaggeredGridView

Comment: I should also mention I'm using Xamarin.Android so u would prefer using android default libraries

Comment: I hope this will solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300577/use-staggered-grid-in-xamarin

Comment: Links are dead @Neha

Comment: I never work on Xamarin but I try if I get some useful links for StaggeredGridView. You can try it at your level.